# How to enable the Group Policy item in batch script

Tags: batch

I want to use a batch script to enable below Printers policy. Any advice, please ?
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Printers\Turn off Windows default printer management

[image]

[image]

Newly Added
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this inside the batch script:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" /v "LegacyDefaultPrinterMode" /d "1" /t reg_dword /f
```

Comment: The registry key is added but the GP does not change. (I already rebooted the PC). See attached picture.

Comment: Look if it is applied, it may not show in GP, but the default printer management should be disabled....

Comment: Do you mean to check that in Printers & Scanners GUI like the picture I added ?

Comment: Yes, to check if Windows is still managing your printers, cause since you changed it from the registry with reg add it may not show on GP